# How is a photoelectron spectrum assigned?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

The photoelectron spectrum of a given molecule is commonly used as experimental evidence of the energy ordering of molecular orbitals (See here:
[10.4: Photoelectron Spectroscopy](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/10%3A_Bonding_in_Polyatomic_Molecules/10.04%3A_Photoelectron_Spectroscopy), and many other physical chemistry books).

How is the experimental photoelectron spectrum assigned? Depending on the molecule you can do an accurate electronic structure calculation, but can it be correctly assigned using only the information in the spectrum (and selection rules, maybe)?

Comment: To be honest, to me it feels like the proof of "orbitals" by photoelectron spectroscopy appears like a of a circular story or a snake biting its own tail. The textbook story goes like this, Xray photoelectron peaks prove that orbitals exist. The next statement is that the XPS peaks are due to electrons ejected from various orbitals. You have correctly guessed nobody ever tells us how they assigned the transitions of hydrogenic like orbitals to almost all elements of the periodic table.

Comment: For an alternative perspective, see John Ogilvie's "Do orbitals exist?" in the Journal of Chemical Education. Also see "Are Orbitals Observable? by Hyle

Comment: Forget about XPS or photoelectron spectra, I have asked various spectroscopists and physicists how did people assign electronic transitions in a simple spectrum such as that of sodium? It is a lost art. Ten years have passed and I am still looking for an answer.

Comment: @M.Farooq thanks for the comments. I wanted to know if there was an origin to this story that you described as "a snake biting its own tail". I'm a computational chemist so I'm aware of their limitations. I was really curious to know if there was a "pure" experimental path to assign these spectra. Too bad that this is a lost art. This could be a nice story to be included in textbooks.

Comment: Dear Antonio, I have used XPS in my research (for analysis) but nobody could tell me how the spectra were assigned. May be we should start with the earliest papers on XPS. As I said, it has been ten years nobody has told me how to experimentally assign the sodium spectral lines. A photoelectron spectrum is way more complicated I guess.

Comment: The snake story refers to an alleged dream by a chemist named Kekule, who was thinking about the structure of benzene. He saw a dream of a snake biting its own tail which gave him a hint of a cyclic structure. I have asked in physics forums, ResearchGate, only get hopeless answers. So far I have not been able to find experimental methodology assignment of electronic transitions in atoms (most likely it is buried in the German literature of 1920s-1930s).